# Codeigniter Authentication and Authorization libraries that works well coupled toghether

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, authorization, codeigniter-2

I need functionality for authentication handling and some basic role based authorization (just block some pages to a role and allow some pages on another).

I already read this question: [What is the best Authentication and Authorization library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252079/what-is-the-best-authentication-and-authorization-library-for-codeigniter)

However the question it's from 2009 so maybe there is a new technology that works better now.
Any suggestion, expecially if you have used the library, are appreciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what you wanted to hear, but I prefer to roll my own classes. I'm not afraid to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: It's a valid answer too, I'll think about it. What I'm afraid is password encryption but I think it's not so hard with a simple hash function

Comment: I prefer to use a salted hash. What I will typically do is take their plain text password and add a string to it derived from a $config item I call $config['encryption_salt']. Then I run the newly built string through php's sha1 function and store the result in the database. :)

Comment: Then when you want to check their entered password during login, just take what they posted, add the salt to it, sha1 it and use that in your select statement against the logins or users table.

Comment: As for authorization, I will typically build a permissions lookup table in my db and assign users a permission_id value in their user record. Then my site can be conditionalized allow or disallow activities based on their permission_id.

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like skittles answer so I post it here (he is not posting):

> I'm pretty sure this is not what you wanted to hear, but I prefer to
>   roll my own classes. I'm not afraid to re-invent the wheel
>
> I prefer to use a salted hash. What I will typically do is take their
>   plain text password and add a string to it derived from a $config item
>   I call $config['encryption_salt']. Then I run the newly built string
>   through php's sha1 function and store the result in the database.
>
> As for authorization, I will typically build a permissions lookup
>   table in my db and assign users a permission_id value in their user
>   record. Then my site can be conditionalized allow or disallow
>   activities based on their permission_id

If Skittle will post answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 0):

All of the Auth libraries I know of restrict you in some form or other out of the bag. Its usually a good idea to build your own auth library, break it down so you dont restrict yourself to using codeigniters native AR.

For role/permissions I usually just store a json object to my permissions column in say `users`.  I prefer this over using a more complicated [technique](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

In my main Controller(non-restrictive) I just create a permissions(array)var and loop through it inside my child controllers to implement a restriction.

**example:**

*sql column*

```
`permissions` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '["r", "u", "d"]';
```

*main controller*

```
protected $permissions = array();

protected function _get_permissions()
{
   return (array)json_encode($this->user->permissions);
   //get permissions from user (array/object)
}
```

*extended children*

```
if(in_array('r', $this->permissions))
{
   //user can read something
}
```